I am using cdk virtual scroll appendOnly mode, but its jerking on scroll
I am using cdk virtual scroll appendOnly mode with angular 13, but its jerking on scroll.
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly
            class="container-fluid table-grid h-100 _dropddownScroll pipeline-main-wrapper" itemSize="100">
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz demo where the issue happens

When using Angular's CDK virtual-scroll-viewport with appendOnly mode, jerky scrolling can happen due to a variety of reasons, such as layout recalculations, heavy reflows, or inefficient change detection. Since you're using appendOnly, the issue could stem from how new items are added, causing the scroll container to reflow or the virtual scroll to load too many items at once.
Here are a few steps to try and improve performance and reduce the jerky scroll behavior:

Check itemSize and Container Size
Ensure that the itemSize is set correctly and reflects the actual size of the items in the list. If the item size is too large or too small, it can cause the virtual scroll to behave unpredictably.




You might want to test setting different itemSize values or dynamically adjusting it based on the item content.

Enable trackBy for Items
To ensure that Angular knows how to efficiently track changes in your list and avoid unnecessary re-renders, always use a trackBy function when iterating over items.

Example:
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly
  class="container-fluid table-grid h-100 _dropddownScroll pipeline-main-wrapper" 
  itemSize="100">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackById">
    <!-- Your list item content here -->
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

In the component class:
trackById(index: number, item: any): any {
  return item.id; // or any unique identifier
}


Use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
Ensure that your component’s change detection strategy is set to OnPush. This can significantly improve performance by reducing unnecessary rechecks of the entire component tree.
@Component({
selector: 'your-component',
templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class YourComponent {
// Component logic here
}

Reduce Layout Thrashing (Reflows/Repaints)
Check for layout thrashing by minimizing DOM updates during scrolling. Make sure that nothing in the component’s template (or other parts of your app) causes unnecessary layout recalculations when the viewport scrolls. Avoid modifying styles directly inside scroll events, and try to minimize complex CSS that could trigger reflows.

Consider Using debounce for Scroll Events
If you're listening to scroll events and triggering updates or changes (e.g., appending new data), consider debouncing the scroll event to reduce the frequency of updates. You can use RxJS to debounce scroll events like this:
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
ngAfterViewInit() {
fromEvent(this.viewport.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scroll')
.pipe(debounceTime(200))  // Adjust debounce time as needed
.subscribe(() => {
// Handle the scroll event here
});
}

Optimize Item Addition
Ensure that new items are appended to the list efficiently. If you're appending a large number of items at once, this can cause performance issues. Try batching updates (e.g., appending items in smaller groups) or optimizing how the new data is handled.

Use virtualScroll vs appendOnly if Possible
If possible, consider using the default virtualScroll mode, which dynamically removes items that are off-screen. appendOnly is specifically for scenarios where you only append items (no removal), and if you don't have a lot of items being removed, you might be better off with a more dynamic approach.

Check for Heavy Operations
Finally, ensure that there are no heavy operations running during scrolling. This could be heavy DOM manipulations, complex pipes, or unnecessary subscriptions being triggered during the scroll event. Optimize those operations to ensure smoother performance.


Summary of Key Adjustments:
Ensure itemSize is accurate.
Use trackBy for efficient rendering of items.
Set change detection to OnPush for better performance.
Minimize reflows/repaints during scroll.
Debounce scroll events if you're performing expensive operations.
Consider smaller batches for adding new items.
If you still encounter issues, you might want to check the browser's performance tools (like Chrome's DevTools) to identify any bottlenecks during scrolling and rendering.

Is this AI-generated?
